# vector of list of string in cpp, "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: c++, memory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<list<string> > testList;
    testList[2].push_back("ADA");
    return 0;
}
```

It got a thread, when program running.
signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

I guesse it's because of illegal memory access,
but I don't know why and how to fix it.

thanks so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`testList` has length 0 after initialization, therefore you cannot access `testList[2]`.

You can pass an initial size to the c'tor of std::vector, so the following should work

```
vector<list<string> > testList(3);
testList[2].push_back("ADA");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `testList` has size of 0 so you can't access element 2. for that you need to resize it:

```
testList.resize(3);
```